# DreamPress WordPress site Varnish Cache Error

Tags: debian, wordpress, varnish

Every now and then, often when I write a post on my Dreamhost [DreamPress](http://www.dreamhost.com/dreampress/) WordPress blog I get this Varnish related error:

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:

XID: 180706672

Varnish cache server
```

I did a related post here https://serverfault.com/questions/576319/varnish-ispconfig-under-debian-give-error-503 but they only tell me it could be an Apache Virtual Hosts issue and that the defined hosts should be checked. But that thread was on a different XID and just a comment, not an accepted solution. So perhaps this situation is different. Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in the error logs for your apache instance?

Comment: [Tue Jun 10 23:21:06 2014] [error] [client 208.80.xxx.xx] File does not exist: /home/me/site.com/wp-content/themes/img/9916153089
[Wed Jun 11 00:08:03 2014] [emerg] [client 72.46.xxx.xxx] (22)Invalid argument: mod_fcgid: can't lock process table in pid 32743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking output of varnishlog may help to diagnose the exact issue causing this error. Since the logs are generated for every single request, you may want to direct logs to a text file and later look for 'Error 503 Service Unavailable' in text file.

Comment: In the end it appeared there was not enough memory. DH increased the memory and things were fixed. Also dumped a few unnecessary plugins to lower memory usage. Think they checked the Varnish logs for me so will check your answer as the best answer.